# Error in nchar(desc) : invalid multibyte string, element 1 when web scraping when using map() and rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, vectorization, rvest

I am trying to scrape multiple webpages more efficiently with `purrrs::map()`. If I use `read_html()` on each link on its own, it works, however, if I try to achieve the same thing with `map()`, R Returns

> Error in nchar(desc) : invalid multibyte string, element 1

Below I pasted a minimal replicable example. The string itself seems to be fine, I entered several strings as Vector into `tmp` and always got the same error. How do I fix this?

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
tmp <- c("https://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-and-invalid-multibyte-string/","https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/")
tmp
# does not work
map(tmp,read_html)
# works
read_html(tmp[1])
read_html(tmp[2])

# suggestion 1
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")
# does still not work
map(tmp,read_html)
# works
read_html(tmp[1])
read_html(tmp[2])

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")

# does still not work
map(tmp,read_html)
# works
read_html(tmp[1])
read_html(tmp[2])
```

Comment: odd... it works for me with _map(tmp,read_html)_